# OpenCL: How does one assign a cl::Buffer from Caffe blob / GPU float*

Tags: opencl, caffe

Caffe is a deep learning library, that also has support for OpenCL. It allows one to access the GPU data pointer directly, and pass int into a CUDA Kernel as follows, if compiled with CUDA:

```
caffe::Blob<T>* topLayer ...
resizeKernel<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(top.at(0)->mutable_gpu_data())

template <typename T>
    __global__ void resizeKernel(T* mutableGpuData){

}
```

Now, if Caffe is compiled with OpenCL, we have the same API to access the GPU data pointer. So I want to ask, how does one convert this into a cl::Buffer without incurring any memory cost?